# jquery changing fullwidth to boxed layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap and with the container class i get a boxed layout (all the content in the middle). i want to make a website which changes to fullwidth when a user clicks on a button. how can i do it?

i tried jquery remove method.

```
<script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() 
        {
            $( ".container" ).remove();
    }
    );
</script>
```

but it removes everything inside the divs with .container class.

Comment: what you want to remove man??

Comment: i want to remove nothing. i just want to convert a boxed website(say 960px wide) to fullwidth website when a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change container width to full like web page. In this case try this one

```
<script>
    $("button").on('click',function(){
           $(".container").css({"width":"100%","height":"100%"});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it's ok. change the Height also

Comment: by the way, is there any method by which i can disable a css class? for example, when a user clicks on a button, the .container class is diabled or removed whatever. please reply.

Comment: use removeClass('class name') method