# Bootstrap CSS for wide and boxed layouts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I need two layouts for wide and boxed. And I want to easly toggle (change) between layouts when needed.

EDIT : How can I do like this : http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.7/
Beetween boxed and wide layout changing only in body class (boxed-layout container) I don't need switcher. I will put "boxed-layout container" class to body for boxed layout or I will remove boxed-layout container class from body for wide layout. But I can not do it with bootstap and need help for this.

How can I create wide and boxed layouts like following example images? And how can I change layout via class?

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.main-wrapper-wide {
width: 100% !important;
}
.main-wrapper-boxed {
width: 850px !important;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-wrapper-wide or main-wrapper-boxed">
<!-- header content here !-->
<!-- slider here !-->
<!-- site content here !-->
<!-- footer content here start !-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use CSS `@media` queries (is it dependent on screen size)? Or use JavaScript to create a user driven toggle?

Comment: @codyogden if possible both of them (css and javascript)

Comment: @webmaster hi did you ever figure and solve this and how did you do it?

Comment: @maxit I didn't resolve completely my problem but if you need click change between boxed and wide layout this link maybe can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681698/jquery-changing-fullwidth-to-boxed-layout

Comment: Your `htmlstream` link is broken. Please update it, or remove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the Navbar and the main containers to only be a max of 800px wide and then still be free to resize on all screens sizes. 
If so then this is probably all you need.

Just use `max-width:800px;` and you also need to `<center>` the divs.

Here is a **[full size Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5vncy21/embedded/result/)**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}   
.clear {
  margin-top:60px;
  margin-bottom:60px;  
}       
.block1 {
  height: 440px;
  margin-bottom:60px;  
} 
.block2 {
  height: 200px; 
}     
.bg-clr {
  background-color: blueviolet;  
}
.bg-clr-blk {
  background-color: black;  
} 
.section-max-width {
  max-width:800px; 
}
b {
  color:black;  
}
</style>

</head>

<body class="bg-clr">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container section-max-width">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<center>    
<section class="section-max-width">

    <div class="clear">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-primary block1">
    <br>    
        The overall <b>Max Width</b> these containers and the navbar can be is <b>800px</b>.
    <br>
    They are still free the reduce in size when resized to fit smaller screen sizes.
    <br>
    Resize to see.
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-primary block2"></div>    
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-clr-blk clear"><br><br></div>

</section>
</center>    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, the website in the link is actually doing what I provided but rather at 800px  around 1200px. You are right there is no need to switch between any views. In the link they contain the navbar and the content to 1200px but they do allow the slider to go full width. Do you want the slider to stay contained like you show or like in the website link.?

Comment: Did you just say `<center>`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code snippet and try changing the `main-wrapper-wide` class to `main-wrapper-boxed`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.main-wrapper-boxed {
  max-width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FF7777;
}
.main-wrapper-boxed .container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.slider {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1C1C1C;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-wrapper-wide"> <!-- change class name to main-wrapper-boxed -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header mx-0">
      <div class="col-3">Logo</div>
      <div class="col-8 offset-1">Header menu</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid slider">
    <div class="container">Slider</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">Site content</div>

  <div class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="container">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These were the steps I took:

1. First of all, I created the page as you wanted in the *Bootstrap wide example*. This became the `main-wrapper-wide` version.
2. After that, I changed the class to `main-wrapper-boxed` and customized it for the *Bootstrap boxed example* by giving it `max-width=850px`.
3. Done!

Here's a <kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258713/)</kbd> just in case...